# Как переместить прокрутку влево

Tags: html, css

Как переместить прокрутку влево, а картинку справа сделать на 100%?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.slider>label {}

.slider>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-size: cover;
}

input[name='slide_switch'] {
  display: none;
}

.slider label {
  margin: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.slider label img {
  display: block;
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
  border-color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch']~img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.leff {
  background-color: rgb(173, 36, 36);
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.leff>label {
  display: block;
  margin: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

.leff>label>img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1" />
  <label for="id1">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" />

  <!--Lets show the second image by default on page load-->
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked" />
  <label for="id2">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3" />
  <label for="id3">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4" />
  <label for="id4">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5" />
  <label for="id5">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" />

</div>
<div class="leff"><input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1" />
  <label for="id1">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <!--Lets show the second image by default on page load-->
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked" />
  <label for="id2">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3" />
  <label for="id3">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4" />
  <label for="id4">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5" />
  <label for="id5">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/trj3vuda/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под *картинкой справа* Вы имели ввиду изображение в блоке `.slider` и нужно растянуть его до блока `.left`, то так:

- `direction: rtl;` - [документация](http://htmlbook.ru/css/direction)
- `width:calc(100% - 253px);` - как вариант, можно обернуть блоки во flex

  ```
  .leff {
    background-color: rgb(173, 36, 36);
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
    direction: rtl;
  }
  .slider {
    /*width: 300px;*/
    width:calc(100% - 253px);
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0px;
    float: right;
  }
  ```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  /*width: 300px;*/
  width:calc(100% - 253px);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.slider>label {}

.slider>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-size: cover;
}

input[name='slide_switch'] {
  display: none;
}

.slider label {
  margin: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.slider label img {
  display: block;
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
  border-color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch']~img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.leff {
  background-color: rgb(173, 36, 36);
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll;
  direction: rtl;
}

.leff>label {
  display: block;
  margin: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

.leff>label>img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1" />
  <label for="id1">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" />

  <!--Lets show the second image by default on page load-->
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked" />
  <label for="id2">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3" />
  <label for="id3">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4" />
  <label for="id4">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5" />
  <label for="id5">

    </label>
  <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" />

</div>
<div class="leff"><input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1" />
  <label for="id1">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <!--Lets show the second image by default on page load-->
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked" />
  <label for="id2">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3" />
  <label for="id3">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4" />
  <label for="id4">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>


  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5" />
  <label for="id5">
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg" width="100"/>
    </label>

</div>
```

Comment: Ну можно сказать одна проблема решена спс, а как скрол убрать справа и влево переместить?

Comment: http://vfl.ru/fotos/f8c3416624290084.html

Comment: @recile справа браузерная прокрутка или прокрутка на блоке `slider` ?

Comment: Да прокрутка на блоке slider нужно

Comment: @recile точно так же: для `.slider` поставьте высоту с ширину, после чего пропишите `overflow-y: scroll; direction: rtl;`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @recile пожалуйста. Если Вам подходит ответ как решение, [отметьте его решением вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от ответа под цифрой. Галка станет зеленой - это означает, что ответ является [решением Вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: ок, не заметил, сделал